# Oracle JDBC and Views

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, view

I am trying to get SELECT statement from a view with executeQuery but i cant get a resultset, the meta data is intact (names and number of columns)
i am also tried change to PreparedStatement and CallableStatement and it is the same

Here is my code

```
private Statement stmt=null;
private ResultSet rset=null;
........
rset = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT STUDENT_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME FROM STUDENT_VIEW");
columnNum=rset.getMetaData().getColumnCount();
toClient.writeInt(columnNum);
for(int i=1;i<=columnNum;i++)
    toClient.writeUTF(rset.getMetaData().getColumnName(i));
if (rset.last()) {
   toClient.writeInt(rset.getRow());
   rset.beforeFirst();
                 }
   while (rset.next())
         for(int i=1;i<=columnNum;i++){
            if(rset.getString(i)!=null)
                  toClient.writeUTF(rset.getString(i));
            else
              toClient.writeUTF(" ");
                                      }
```

in the debug mode java can't execute rset.last() command

but when i do

```
rset = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM STUDENT_VIEW")
```

the code run perfectly.
Can some one help?

the STUDENT_VIEW

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW STUDENT_VIEW
AS
SELECT 
    s.student_id,s.first_name,s.last_name,s.phone,s.birth_date,s.street,
    s.zip_code,d.name as Department,d.credits_to_degree,s.credits,s.eligible,c.name as College
FROM 
    STUDENT s,DEPARTMENT d,COLLEGE c
WHERE
    s.department=d.department_id and d.college_id=c.college_id;
```

The other tables

```
create table Department (
             Department_ID varchar(4) not null,
             Name varchar(25) unique,
             Department_Head_ID varchar(9),
             College_ID varchar(4),
             Credits_To_Degree NUMBER(3),
             Students NUMBER(3),
             Faculty NUMBER(3),constraint pkDepartment primary key (Department_ID));

ALTER TABLE Department ADD FOREIGN KEY (Department_Head_ID) REFERENCES  Faculty(Faculty_Id) INITIALLY DEFERRED;
ALTER TABLE Department ADD FOREIGN KEY(College_ID) REFERENCES College(College_ID) INITIALLY DEFERRED;

create table Student (
             Student_ID varchar(9) not null, 
             First_Name varchar(25),
             Last_Name varchar(25), 
             Phone char(11), 
             Birth_Date date, 
             Street varchar(100), 
             Zip_Code char(5),
             Department varchar(4),
             Credits integer,
             Eligible char(4), constraint pkStudent primary key (Student_ID),constraint fkDeptId foreign key (Department) references Department(Department_ID));

create table College(
             College_ID varchar(4) not null,
             Name varchar(25), 
             Since date, 
             Dean_ID varchar(9),constraint pkCollege primary key (College_ID));
```

Comment: I suppose that `selectQuery()` masks the creation and execution of the `stmt` statement. What is the error/exception you get? Please put it in the question.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the definition of STUDENT_VIEW. Thanks.

Comment: i edited the question.for the error i don't get any, after the rset.last() command it just jumps to the end of the code (i know that it is a very strange behavior)

Comment: Have you verified using e.g. sql*plus that your query should actually return any rows? What I mean is - could this be a defect of the view itself or the data in the tables causing the view to not return any rows?

Comment: That's the first thing that i did. and in sql developer i'm getting the data normally